# MySQL INSERT INTO inside UPDATE and SET new primary key as foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table where some of the referenced `datastores` have been deleted and their foreign key reference nulled. I need to insert a fresh `datastore` and set the foreign key in the reference table.

All of the IDs are `UUIDs` and my pseudo query looks like this but does not work:

```sql
UPDATE `rcachievements_player_achievements`
SET data_id = (INSERT INTO `rcachievements_datastore` (data) VALUES ('{"count":0}'))
WHERE data_id is null
```

Is there any way to insert the `datastore` and then set the `id` in the `data_id` field for every row that has a missing data store?
[image: table structure]

Comment: Where are you setting the `id` of the row you're inserting?

Comment: Very strange algorithm... if rows with `data_id is null` exists then the all of them must be updated? and when none such rows then none rows must be updated accordingly?

Comment: Yes and every row with a missing data store must get its own new store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it with a [FOR LOOP](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/for/), like the following:

```sql
DELIMITER //

FOR i IN (SELECT id FROM `rcachievements_player_achievements` WHERE data_id is NULL)
DO
        SET @id = UUID();
        INSERT INTO `rcachievements_datastore` (id, data, version, when_created, when_modified) VALUES (@id, '{"count":0}', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
        UPDATE `rcachievements_player_achievements` SET data_id = @id WHERE id = i.id;
END FOR;
//

DELIMITER ;

SELECT id FROM `rcachievements_player_achievements` WHERE data_id is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it as multiple queries. First insert the new row into `rcachievements_datastore`, then update all the referencing rows.

```
SET @id = UUID();
INSERT INTO `rcachievements_datastore` (id, data) VALUES (@id, '{"count":0}');

UPDATE `rcachievements_player_achievements`
SET data_id = @id
WHERE data_id is null;
```

Comment: This does not work as it will only generate one store. But I need one store per missing data_id (over 3000)

Comment: In that case you'll need to use a language with loops, not SQL.

Comment: You can do it in MySQL with a stored procedure.